# how can I change the value of an object in an array being mapped from state react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping, javascript-objects, helper

i'm building the simplest cart system that doesn't require payment or auth, just show product and i'm at the point where...

i'm showing (mapping) all items in [cart] and the user should be able to type the quantity they want.

having trouble with my handleChange helper

i've tried spreading and creating a copy of cart

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const lights = [ ...this.props.cart ]
    const editCount = { ...lights }
    editCount[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({ editCount })
}
```

```
const finalCart = this.props.cart
        const cartCard = finalCart.map((light, i) => {
            return (
              <Card key={i}>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>
                      <Image alt="test" src={light.image} height="100"/>
                      </Col>
                      <Col>
                      <div id="lightName">{light.partnumber}</div>
                      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Control size='sm' type='text' name='count' value={this.state.editCount.count} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                      </Form>
                </Container>
              </Card>
```

i cant quite get a hold of a dynamic light in my handleChange, i can hard code it from other examples on stackoverflow but nothing show how to dynamically grab the specific item who's form i'm clicking (changing)

i just get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by using `onChange={() => this.handleChange(light.name, light.value)}`
and directly passing the value in handleChange function rather than event 
may be like

```
handleChange = (name,value) => {
    const lights = [ ...this.props.cart ]
    const editCount = { ...lights }
    editCount[name] = value
    this.setState({ editCount })
}
```

Comment: interesting.... i've never done that before, i just want to change a single quality of it, any examples i could read through?